# Is the set $X:=\{(x,y,z)^T \in \Bbb R^{3}|f(x,y,z)=0,g(x,y,z)\le 0\}$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Where $f(x,y,z):=x+z-1\text{ and }g(x,y,z):=y^2-xz$

I tried to prove the convexity of the set $X$ by showing it is the intersection of two convex sets. $f(x,y,z) = 0$ is a hyperplane and $g(x,y,z)\le 0$ is a half-space. Since both of these types of sets are convex, the intersection is convex. But I think this pseudo-proof is not specific enough. Should I try to prove that $f(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$ are convex functions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'half-space'? Drawing the graph of $g$ doesn't look like it cuts $\mathbb R^3$ in half.

Comment: The equation $$f(x,y,z)=0$$ defines a plane, which is clearly convex. The equation $$g(x,y,z)\le 0$$ looks parabolic in planes parallel to xy and yz planes, but hyperbolic in planes parallel to xz plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,y,z)\in X$. Then since $z=1-x$, $y^2-x(1-x)=x^2-x+y^2\le 0$. Hence $$\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2\le 1, z=1-x$$
implies that $X$ is actually convex.